# How to add checkbox column to a table built from a sqlalchemy query and displayed using flask_table

Tags: flask, sqlalchemy, jinja2

My flask-based site has tables that could be from your first flask tutorial: built from a sqlalchemy query whose result is passed to the constructor of a Table subclass, then displayed with a simple {{table}} in a jinja2 template file.

Now I want to enclose the table in a form with a "Delete selected" button at the top.
And I want to add a new column, a checkbox that lets the user select rows to be deleted. I either need to get my Table subclass to add a checkbox column that's part of a single form (not like ButtonCol, where each is in its own form), or tweak the table's html before (or during) the rendering process.

I can't be the first to want to do this, but I can't find any support in flask_table, which seems the logical place to start. I'm probably too new to this to know where to look. Any pointers or suggestions?

Thanks,

--Eric